# how to submit form data using formdata object from one form to another form using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to submit 1st form data to another remote form data using formdata object and jquery ajax, finally get result from remote form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, is a bit undefined question but I'll try my best.

First of all you need an HTML or PHP where you will recieve data from AJAX form, like:

```
<div id="ajaxform">
     <button id="ajaxform" class="button"></button>      
</div>
```

Then, in your javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(init);

    function init() {
          $('#ajaxform').click(sendAJAX);
        }

        function sendAJAX(){   
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "yourPHP.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {//data to send using JSON
},
                        success: function (respJSON) {
                            var X= respJSON.X;
                            var Y= respJSON.Y;
                }
        }
```

Now, you have to edit your PHP, as:

```
 <?php
    //your data from HTML as:
    $varZ = $_POST['varZ'];

    //Code where edit data, etc

    echo ($respJSON);
    ?>
```

Hope it helps, if you improve your question I can edit my answer to make it less general.